# Grk0 fonts in LaTex

Tags: fonts

I have to write in a LaTex document some word using the grk0 font. Is there such font or similar in LaTex?

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Maurizio

Comment: Supposedly a Greek font, you should check on how to use Greek in Latex. Or, if you have the font, check out `fontspec`.

Comment: Any more information about grk0?

Comment: Well, the font is installed in my computer. LibreOffice can read it. But I don't know how handle it.